# Will GPU virtualization help improve remote desktop WPF application's performance?

Tags: wpf, rdp

I am developing a WPF application. It works perfectly on my laptop, and it worked perfectly on a local area network remote desktop as well. However, it does not seem to work on a remote desktop where the server is virtualized by VMWare in somewhere else. The remote machine in the local area network has a graphic card. The remote server somewhere else does not have a graphic card.

Now, I enforced the rendering mode of my WPF application to be "Software", using:

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

Will GPU virtualization help improve remote desktop WPF application's performance?

Comment: Are you comparing a Citrix terminal-services environment to a LAN RDP session between two machines? I'm not sure that's a fair test (MS terminal services would be a better comparison). Also, this probably depends on what your WPF application is doing: I've had WPF apps running on Citrix before with no issues. It would also help if you can be more precise: you've said "didn't work perfectly," "works nicely" and "runs much better" - but those phrases could mean anything.

Comment: Hi @Dan Puzey. I've an application with TreeListView's, thousand rows and more than 50 columns. I used DevExpres's GridControl, and did my best to avoid effects which need GPUs. If i scrolls TreeListView, it will invoke the re-drawings of dirty-regions. It means the remote server have to compress dirty-regions bitmaps and send them to my client PC. It costs really too much.

Comment: No it is not clear what you are asking.   You switch servers,  RDP to Critix, and if GPU is on the client or server.  Pick one simple question at a time to ask.

Comment: Hi @Blam An WPF application running on a RDP remote server. This WPF application was set to Software rendering mode. Will a graphic card improve this remote WPF applcation's performance? I mean will this graphic card help RDP to compress bitmaps faster.

Comment: Test. And why do you think the only way it could help performance is to help compression?

Comment: Hi @Blam I've no idea. Because my wpf application worked nicely on local area network remote desktop. But it works badly on remote desktop where the server is virtualized by VMWare in somewhere else. The remote machine in local area network has a graphic card. The remote server somewhere else doesn't have a graphic card.

Comment: @BoHU: it's not just about the presence of a graphics card; it's also the configuration of servers and connections. Local RDP will always be more performant because you have less latency and typically higher bandwidth on your connection than with a remote, shared server. Also, terminal services (which is designed to support mutliple users) is likely to have more conservative default settings than an RDP session that was set up for a single user. Ultimately I think it's clear that this isn't a programming question - I'd vote for this to be moved to SuperUser.com.